# Are the multiple copies of schemas_microsoft_com_2003_10_Serialization needed?

Tags: xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment, btdf

Working on a BTDF deployment package, firstly the schema, and getting lots of warnings that ...

> a previously deployed schema "" have the same target namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/".

which track back to the various copies of the `..._schemas_microsoft_com_2003_10_Serialization.xsd`, presumably added by referencing multiple web services.

Are these all needed? ... *especially as the content is identical*

Is even one needed?

Similarly, there are multiple copies of the `...Serialization_Arrays.xsd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, multiple copies of these schemas do not have to be *Deployed*.  But...

These schema are included in Projects when you generate schemas for WCF Adapter services though with different .Net Type names and namespaces.  They only thing they contain are element type definitions and are used by the referring schema.

But, not every definition is used and yes, it does tend to clutter the Schemas list in BT Admin.

So, there are some ways to mitigate this:

1. Have one "master" Serialization.xsd, and reference it from any other WCF schema.  One per Solution is an option too, whichever is most practical.
2. Remove the reference completely by changing to native xml types.  Most of the definitions are redeclarations of native types and likely aren't used.  Checking a couple schemas I have at hand, I see only the "guid" type is used.  It still works fine if I change it to xs:string and remove ...Serialization.xsd from the Includes list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah clutter the Admin Console, but even worse, they get flagged as warnings in the BTDF build, which means a manual check to confirm they are "known" issues ... grr, back to the developers to clean up their solution  :-)